# JQuery Dialog Box Double Posting

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple confirmation dialog box that will open when a customer attempts to submit a payment.  If they click 'Cancel' it brings them back to the asp page to re-enter their information but if they click 'Submit Payment' it will fire off a hidden button which calls a method in the code behind to process the payment.  The problem I am having is that some customers are apparently able to click the 'Submit Payment' button twice before the dialog box closes.  Is there anything I can do on my side to prevent the button from being clicked twice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowPaymentConfirmation() {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-ReviewPmt").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            dialogClass: "noclose",
            closeOnEscape: false,
            modal: true,
            width: '650px',
            "title": "Review Payment",
            buttons: {
                "Submit Payment": { "class": "SubmitPaymentDialogButton", click: function () {
                    this.disabled = true;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#<%=PaymentSubmit.ClientID%>").click();
                }
                },
                "Cancel": { "class": "CancelRedDialogButton", click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Why can't you just disable it on the first click?

Comment: Do you mean to disable to hidden button or to disable the dialog button?  The confusing thing to me is that the very first thing this button should be doing is closing the dialog box, so I am wondering how effective other client side controls will be.  I will try to add your suggestion as an additional precaution as well but sadly i am unable to replicate the issue so that makes testing potential fixes difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comments, but I can't reproduce the issue.  No matter how fast I double-click a button, it does not fire its click callback twice.

Is it possible your ShowPaymentConfirmation() function is being called twice?

Comment: I do not believe my ShowPaymentConfirmation()  funciton is being called twice since there is only one button that calls that function.  Reproducing the issue is indeed my biggest problem but I think I have come up with a back end solution to prevent this from happening.  The method in the code behind takes information from a session variable called 'ReviewPayment' to process the payment.  I think I am going to add a step to clear out 'ReviewPayment' when 'Submit Payment' is clicked and set it to a value called 'ConfirmPayment'.  That way the values wont exist for a second click.